Почему не меняется цвет шрифта и не меняются шрифты
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.font import * 
def colour(n): 
    if n == 0: 
        ent1.config(fg= "red") 
    elif n == 1: 
        ent1.config(fg = "green") 
    elif n == 2: 
        ent1.config(fg="blue") 
    elif n == 3: 
        ent1.config(fg="yellow") 
    elif n == 4: 
        ent1.config(fg="pink") 

def color(m): 
    if m == 0: 
        ent1.config(bg="Red") 
    elif m == 1: 
        ent1.config(bg="Green") 
    elif m == 2: 
        ent1.config(bg="blue") 
    elif m == 3: 
        ent1.config(bg="yellow") 
    elif m == 4: 
        ent1.config(bg="pink") 

def textt(t): 

    if t == 0: 
        ent1.config(Font = "Verdana") 
    elif t == 1: 
        ent1.config(bg="Green") 
    elif t == 2: 
        ent1.config(bg="blue") 
    elif t == 3: 
        ent1.config(bg="yellow") 
    elif t == 4: 
        ent1.config(bg="pink") 



n = 0 
root = Tk() 
m = Menu(root) 
font1 = Font(family="Arial") 
font2 = Font(family="Drew Fraktur") 
font3 = Font(family="Hello Winds DEMO") 
font4 = Font(family="Bell MT") 
font5 = Font(family="Verdana") 
root.geometry("400x500") 
fra = Frame(root, width=300, height=100) 
fra.pack() 
ent1 = Text(fra) 
ent1.pack() 
root.config(menu=m) 

fm = Menu(m) 
m.add_cascade(label="цвет", menu=fm) 
nfm = Menu(fm) 
rfm = Menu(fm) 

fm.add_cascade(label="цвет фона", menu=nfm) 
nfm.add_command(label="Красный", command=lambda m=0: color(m)) 
nfm.add_command(label="Зеленый", command=lambda m=1: color(m)) 
nfm.add_command(label="голубой", command=lambda m=2: color(m)) 
nfm.add_command(label="желтый", command=lambda m=3: color(m)) 
nfm.add_command(label="розовый", command=lambda m=4: color(m)) 

fm.add_cascade(label="цвет текста", menu=nfm) 
rfm.add_command(label="Красный", command=lambda n=0: colour(n)) 
rfm.add_command(label="Зеленый", command=lambda n=1: colour(n)) 
rfm.add_command(label="голубой", command=lambda n=2: colour(n)) 
rfm.add_command(label="желтый", command=lambda n=3: colour(n)) 
rfm.add_command(label="розовый", command=lambda n=4 :colour(n)) 



hm = Menu(m) 
hml = Menu(hm) 

m.add_cascade(label="шрифт", menu=hm) 
hm.add_cascade(label="шрифт", menu = hml) 
hml.add_command(label="Arial", command=lambda t=0:textt(t)) 
hml.add_command(label="Зеленый", command=lambda n=1:color(n)) 
hml.add_command(label="голубой", command=lambda n=2:color(n)) 
hml.add_command(label="желтый", command=lambda n=3:color(n)) 
hml.add_command(label="розовый", command=lambda n=4:color(n)) 

hm.add_command(label="начертание") 
root.mainloop() 










mainloop()


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Какой-то у вас код полудописанный. Копипаста сплошная, причём где-то исправленная, где-то нет. Уберите всё лишнее, начните с одного меню. И назовите переменные нормально. Вы там сами не путаетесь что такое m, fm, hm и т.д.? Зачем вы буквы экономите?
